# how can I save time when I use reduce operation?

Tags: apache-spark

I use reduce operation to process data on cluster, but i find it cost too much time. The type of the RDD to reduce is:

```
RDD[(Array[Array[Double]], Array[Array[Double]], Array[Double], Array[Double])]
```

Question1: if the type of rdd is simple like RDD[Array[Double]], maybe it cost less time?
Question2: any other way for me to save time when using rdd.reduce?

Comment: Hard to help if we don't see what kind of reduction you are attempting. Could be anything.

Comment: Let us know how u are getting this RDD. May be you are using map instead of flatMap.

Answer (score 0):

ReduceByKey method takes two argument- reduceByKey(func, [numTasks]). First is fuction, whatever operation you want to perform on it, Second is "number of task" it's optional argument.

Set the optimum number of task, depends on your machine configuration.

For example.
**Rdd.redueceByKey(func,4)** 
It will create four parallel process/task to perform reduce operation. And it will be four time faster than your current performance.

Comment: thank you,but I am trying to use reduce operation because i want a array as my return result,so how can i do?